# how to test facebook application with extended permissions, without asking for review

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-permissions

i have read all the answers ( i could find on the matter), and they say, if you are a developer, tester or admin of the application, you should be able to test the app without any problem. I have tried as a admin of the app, developer, tester etc (all the roles given in the developer dashboard) no luck, next i have tried with the test users, still no luck, when i ask the user for the permission (publish_stream), the popup always says

> Submit for Login Review Some of the permissions below have not been
>   approved for use by Facebook.

I have setup the "privacy policy link", i have uploaded the application icon, entered the  application description, still no luck. in the mean time, the other two permissions i ask (user_photos and email) work with no problem.
I can't get what i am doing wrong. has anyone had problems like this?how did he manage to solve them? any help will be much appreciated. 
P.S the only thing i haven't tried is to submit the freaking app for review, but the app is far from done, so i think, the review will be rejected

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You really don´t need to go through the review process for testing, unapproved permissions work for every Admin, Developer or Tester of the App. `publish_stream` is deprecated though, what you probably want is `publish_actions`.

If it still does not work with an Admin/Dev/Tester and the `publish_actions` permission, i´d suspect a bug. In that case you could report it: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: will give it a try as soon as developers.facebook.com comes online. 10x

Comment: well i feel kinda stupid now :). haven't noticed that the new permission is called public_actions. 10x

Comment: yeah, publish_stream was co-existing with publish_actions for a while but got deprecated some months (or even years?) ago afaik :)